# How to bypass .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-clone

We are trying to set up a new staging server and are attempting a `git clone`.  We would like to one-time pull files from our .gitignore (data files which should exist but don't need to be current).  Is there a way to ignore .gitignore just this once?

Comment: `git add -f <files>`

Comment: The only thing is that once you add it, if the files are modified, it won't matter if they are on .gitignore, git won't ignore it.

Comment: Screw that lol, would be easier to manually copy...  was just starting to try it, probably not going to.

Comment: "We would like to one-time pull files from our .gitignore"—you can do this outside of Git. Git can't help with files it isn't tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just have the files on default state on remote repository, remove the files from .gitignore, and ignore changes that will be made on already-tracked files locally using:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree [filepath]
```

Every collaborators of your project should ideally do this so they can modify the files locally without affecting the ones on remote repository.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for.  I see your example scenario as probably more useful than mine, it's mainly so we're not syncing large folders of pdf docs, etc.  Probably somewhere around 15 to 20 GB we don't need tracked continuously.  Thanks man